# How to color Winston logger?

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I've been reading the [documentation](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) but I can't find a way to have color. I set the colors available by winston in `colorsLogger` and pass them to `addColor()` as a parameter. After creating the transport I declare `colorize` as `true`.

```
const { addColors, createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');

const transportsList = [];

const colorsLogger = {
    error: 'red',
    warn: 'yellow',
    info: 'cyan',
    debug: 'green'
};

addColors(colorsLogger);

transportsList.push(
    new transports.Console({
        colorize: true,
        prettyPrint: true,
        format: format.combine(
            format.printf(info => `[${info.timestamp}] ${info.level}: ${info.message}`),
        )
    })
);

const logger = createLogger({
    format: format.combine(
        format.timestamp({ format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss' }),
        format.json()),
    transports: transportsList
});

module.exports = logger;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need provide the `colorize` as a function. Something like this

```
transportsList.push(
  new transports.Console({
    "prettyPrint": true,
    "format": format.combine(
      format.colorize(), // see this
      format.printf(info => `[${info.timestamp}] ${info.level}: ${info.message}`)
    )
  })
);
```

Hope this helps.